# How to display figures using RScript?

Tags: r, plot, figure, rscript

I know RScript is non-interactive, but I would like to display figures without running into the R interactive console first (the same way as in python and java).

In other words, I am hoping to be able to run a single build command from command prompt or terminal that runs an R script and displays its figures.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with [shiny](http://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/) you can build simple shinyApp to display `file.png` file in browser:

```sh
Rscript -e 'png("file.png"); plot(1:10); dev.off(); runApp("display_png_app")'
```

Good comment by @Ista: you don't need to use shiny, you can simply use `browseURL("file.png")` command instead `runApp`.

Comment: You don't need shiny for this, `browseURL` should do the trick, i.e., `Rscript -e 'png("file.png"); plot(1:10); dev.off(); browseURL("file.png");'`. It's worth pointing out that the basic issue here is that graphics devices opened by R will be closed when the script finishes, so we need to open the image in a separate application. Anything that accomplishes that should work.

Comment: @Ista, you are so awesome! This worked great, and I couldn't find this answer anywhere else. Could you please write this comment as an answer so I can vote it as a correct, elegant answer?

Comment: @issamou well my solution is just a small modification to Jan's, I suggest accepting this answer.